# Статус пользователя online/offline

Tags: php

Уважаемые помогите решить проблему! Вот я написал скрипт который должен проверять активность пользователя если он не активен то будет показываться статус офлайн ну это другая часть кода....сам по себе скрипт работает почти т.к обновляет время в бд но почему то не завершает сессию....прошу помочь и объяснить в чем проблема..

```
if (empty($_SESSION['name']) or empty($_SESSION['password'])) {

    }

    else {

    $names_on = $_SESSION['name'];
    $offline_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online WHERE name='$names_on'");    
    $offline = mysql_fetch_array($offline_query);
    $offline_time = date("H-i-s");
    $online_time = $offline['time'];

        if ($online_time < $offline_time) {
        #echo "Время соединения вышло";
        $ofline_del = mysql_query("DELETE SET online WHERE name='$names_on'");
        session_destroy();
        }

        elseif($online_time >= $offline_time) {
            #echo "пока все ок";
            $lim = 90;
            $update_time = date("H:i",time()+$lim);
            $update_query = mysql_query("UPDATE online SET time = '$update_time' WHERE name='$names_on'");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сравниваете строку и объект типа DateTime, $online_time и $offline_time соответственно.

---

**Решение:**

```
// Изменить строку
$online_time = $offline['time'];
// На эту
$online_time = strtotime($offline['time']);
// Или на эту для PHP 5 >= 5.2.0
$online_time = new DateTime($offline['time']);
```

Comment: ситуация осталась прежней....:(

Comment: Пропишите перед
"if ($online_time < $offline_time) {"
строку
"die("$online_time, $offline_time");""
И покажите результат.

Comment: я вот думаю может надо сделать так что бы это скрипт выполнялся в фоновом режиме но как это сделать не знаю.........:(( 

p.s для того что бы он постоянно сравнивал и давал результат а не после обновления страницы....

Comment: 16:20, 16-28-49

Comment: Спасибо! Все сделал проблема была действительно в сравнивание времени т.к формат различался!!!

Comment: А если у тебя пользователь не активен, а просто держит страницу открытой, как ты определяешь онлайн он или нет?